# How do I combine Google forms when the total number of questions in them exceeds the maximum provided by the service?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

There are several forms that contain quite a large number of questions. Each form refers to a specific part of the questionnaire - they need to be combined so that the user passes each part at a time. I need to logically connect these forms to each other. It is not possible to collect them in one form, because the total number of questions in them exceeds the allowed maximum of Google Forms. Are there ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it would be to create a script that [sends an email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) to the [form respondent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getrespondentemail) once they [submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) an answer, sending the link to the next form.

If you want to combine answers of multiple forms in one spreadsheet, then you'd need to include this logic in the triggers of each form.
This case can get a bit more complex, because of situations like multiple users answering forms simultaneously, users using different emails to answer different forms, users answering a form multiple times, etc.